# having runtimewarning overflow errors in long scalers

Tags: python

I am about to compute the fibbonacci series for any particular number, say n. So, I used the numpy library to convert the list to an array. But whenever I try to assign the value for the current item in the iteration by summing up the previous elements in the series, I get this error: having runtimewarning overflow errors in long scalers.
here is my code for the problem:

```
import numpy
f = list()
for i in range(0,200):
    f.append(-1)
fi = numpy.array(f)
def fibbo():
    fi[0]=0
    fi[1]=1
    for i in range(2,200):
        k = fi[i-1]
        j = fi[i-2]
        fi[i]=k + j # I am getting error at this line.

def findfibbo(n):
    return fi[n+1]
fibbo()
n = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 200."))
print(findfibbo(n))
```

I am getting error at this line: `fi[i] = k+j`

Answer (score 0):

F(200) is 280571172992510140037611932413038677189525.
It no longer fits in an integer of 64 bits, it "overflows".

Use (inaccurate but fast) floating point numbers, or use some (accurate but slow) BigInt library.

Comment: is there a way to use long numbers? does python support long integers?